# Delete lines from a file if a numeric pattern is found

Tags: shell

I'd need to remove lines from a file which contain a number. The number is enclosed in parenthesis (The comments in the file are for demo purposes only)

```
line1 (5)  # I want this to be removed
line2      # not to be removed
lineX (21) # I want this to be removed
```

My attempts with sed have been fruitless so far.

```
sed '/*.([1-9][0-9])$/d' file.txt
```

Any idea why it's not working ?

Comment: To remove the whole line `sed '/\ \ *([0-9][0-9]*)/d' file`

Comment: Change `*.` to `.*`